# How to add conditional HTML meta tag using drupal_add_html_head to force only IE9 into compatibility mode?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

Long story short: Some quite nice interative SVG map works fine on every major web browser thanks to [svgweb](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/). Except IE, of course. Every IE (8, 9, 10) needs a particular workaround. IE9 would only work when I force it into compatibility mode. Unfortunately I can't find a way to use `drupal_add_html_head` with `#tag' => meta` and `#prefix` and `#suffix` to only take effect in IE9. `drupal_add_html_head` works fine, but `#prefix` and `#suffix` discard it. So that doesn't work:

```
$meta_ie_render_engine = array(
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible',
    'content' =>  'IE=7',
  ),
  '#weight' => '-99999',
  '#prefix' => '<!--[if IE 9]>',
  '#suffix' => '<![endif]-->',
);
drupal_add_html_head($meta_ie_render_engine, 'meta_ie_render_engine');
```

Is there another way to use `drupal_add_html_head` with `tag => meta` conditionally? Or another drupal-like alternative?

Comment: I would just hardcode the X-UA-Compatible meta tag into your html.tpl.php file in your theme folder. That's an acceptable way of doing it.

Comment: Isn't there anything I can add to my already existing SVG module to keep everything in one place? That would make Features export/import and also future maintainance easier.

Comment: I don't know what your svg module does or how it relates to this particular question. But just modify your theme template found in `/sites/all/themes/<yourtheme>/html.tpl.php`. That's typically what you do in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar problem:

```
function detect_ie() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

above will detect if IE in general. You will need to change 'MSIE' accordingly (something  like 'MSIE9' but not sure if thats correct).

Then what i did was

```
if(detect_ie()) {
  $element = array(
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => array(
  'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible',
    'content' =>  'IE=EmulateIE7',
     ),
  );
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'IE_cr_ap');
}
```

Comment: UA detection on the server side will mess this up when you enable caching.

Comment: It's `'MSIE 9.0'`.